# Why std::uniform_real_distribution::max() returns the exclusive upper bound?

Tags: c++

I'm asking mostly out of academic interest.

The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) says that `std::uniform_real_distribution` generates numbers in `[a,b)` range, where `a` and `b` are the constructor parameters.

Since the upper bound is exclusive, I expect `.max()` to return the *largest representable value less than `.b()`*.

But instead I'm getting `.b() == .max()` on both GCC, Clang, and MSVC. (For `float`, `double`, and `long double`.) Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    auto d = std::uniform_real_distribution<long double>(0, 1);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(1000);
    std::cout << d.min() << '\n'; // 0
    std::cout << d.a() << '\n';   // 0 
    std::cout << d.max() << '\n'; // 1 <- Here I expect 0.99999...
    std::cout << d.b() << '\n';   // 1
}
```

---

I found [this note](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution#Notes) saying that some common implementation use `[a,b]` range for `float` only. It could explain `.b() == .max()` for `float`, but not for `double` and `long double`.

---

> I think it might be educational to also print `std::nextafter(d.b(), d.a())`. – StoryTeller

For `long double` it evaluates to `0.9999999999999999999457898913757247782996273599565029144287109375`, which is what I'd expect to get from `.max()`.

Comment: The standard defines that the `max()` returns the *least upper bound* or supremum in mathematical term (as in [rand.req.dist] 3.d), which is exactly `b` for real interval `[a, b)`.

Comment: @YiFei - Floating point numbers are not real numbers. In particular, they are not contiguous. So the LUB of the real interval may not be (and actually isn't) the LUB of the *discrete* interval. This is the point The OP is making, me thinks.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - I think it might be educational to also print `std::nextafter(d.b(), d.a()) `.

Comment: @StoryTeller. I'm not a standard expert, but I don't think the standard specifies what float point types are supposed to be implemented (at least as in `[basic.fundamental]`). So maybe `double` *could*(potentially) represent `real` in the mathematical sense.

Comment: @YiFei - True, it doesn't specify an implementation. But it does recognize they have certain precision (it specifies `double` must offer at least as much precision as `float`). So I don't think the standard can substitute any floating point type for "reals" in good conscience.

Comment: Side note: The digits you displayed are mostly noise.  You could use [max_digits10](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10) with set_precision.

Comment: From [C++11 draft](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c%2b%2b/c%2b%2b11_n3337.txt) one can see that `26.5.6. random_device::operator()` returns value `... between min() and max(), inclusive.`, and in `26.5.8.2.2` the `uniform_real_distribution random number distribution produces random numbers x, a <= x < b ...`. But the [libcxx implementation](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/random#L3759) just returns `b()` in `max()`. I guess it should return `std::nextafter(b(), a());` ?

Comment: `uniform_real_distribution` can be instantiated with non-standard types, like an arbitrary precision big number class, that do not have a `nextafter`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the bug is about **floats** specifically, but for floating point numbers in general.

The bug was already mentioned in
[VS-Dev-Community](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/110322)
where this problem is addressed with regards to **doubles**.
However, they claim to have it fixed as of Jan 26, 2021.

On a side note:
Also, I cannot reproduce the max() value you get for long double. I get 1 as in all other cases.
As mentioned before, it is just random noise, since setprecision(n) seems to produce noise for n > numeric_limits::max_digits10.

Comment: *"I do not think the bug is about floats specifically"* Yes, since `.max() == 1` for all floating-point types. *"cannot reproduce the max() value you get for long double. I get 1"* I get `1` too, I didn't say otherwise. *"random noise [at large precision]"* It's not noise, I believe it to be the exact number represented by a variable. You can't control the lower digits because of the lack of precision, yes, but the digits themselves are not random.

Comment: Huh? You said,  "For long double it evaluates to 0.9999999999999999999457898913757247782996273599565029144287109375, which is what I'd expect to get from .max()."

Comment: That's what `std::nextafter` returns, not `.max()`.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug and results from the representation of real numbers in binary format. There may be rounding errors.

You already gave the answer by yourself.

You are linking to cppreference. And here, in the notes, is a further link to [LWG issue 2524](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-active.html#2524)

This again links to [P0952](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0952r0.html), which proposes a solution.

Please check the resulting value. And if 1, then call the function again. This will give give a small statistical deviation from a perfect distribution. But better than having a problem with getting inf by calculating 1/(1-r) and crashing the next moon rocket . . .

Comment: As the question says, I don't think this bug is related. The bug is about `float`s specifically, but `.max()` returns seemingly incorrect values for `double` and `long double` as well.